# I can't concatenate correctly to the source of the image

Tags: php, laravel, concatenation, laravel-9

I have the following problem: I cannot concatenate correctly, so that my image is sent from the form. the rest of the fields work without problems

```
<h1><strong>Fecha IP:</strong>{{$siniestro['fechaip']}}</h1>
    

    
<div>

<p><strong>E-mail:</strong>{{$siniestro['email']}}</p>
<p><strong>Patente:</strong>{{$siniestro['patente']}}</p>
<a href="{{$siniestro['link']}}"><strong>Link 2.0</strong></a>
<p><strong>Observaciones:</strong>{{$siniestro['observaciones']}}</p>
<img alt="img" src="/img/{{ $siniestro->['imagen'] }}" width="100px">


</div>
```

[image: here attached capture of the error that sends me]

if i apply the code

```
<img alt="img" src="/img/{{ $siniestro->['imagen'] }}" width="100px">
```

it gives me the error

syntax error, unexpected token "[", expecting identifier or variable or "{" or "$

Comment: that isn't a valid syntax for PHP .. not sure where you saw that before

Comment: Try replacing `$siniestro->['imagen']` with `$siniestro['imagen']`.

Comment: I've tried it, and it keeps giving me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<?php __(your code here)__ ?>` or `<?-- __(your code here)__ ?>` whenever you use php variables between html code.

Comment: it keeps giving me an error buddy. this is frustrating